# Correct usage of addEventListener() / attachEvent()?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, attachevent

I'm wondering how to use `addEventListener` respectively `attachEvent` correctly?

```
window.onload = function (myFunc1) { /* do something */ }

function myFunc2() { /* do something */ }

if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', myFunc2, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent('onload', myFunc2);
}

 // ...
```

or

```
function myFunc1() { /* do something */ }

if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', myFunc1, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent('onload', myFunc1);
}

function myFunc2() { /* do something */ }

if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', myFunc2, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent('onload', myFunc2);
}

 // ...
```

?

Is this cross-browser secure or should I better go with something like this:

```
function myFunc1(){ /* do something */ }
function myFunc2(){ /* do something */ }
// ...

function addOnloadEvent(fnc){
  if ( typeof window.addEventListener != "undefined" )
    window.addEventListener( "load", fnc, false );
  else if ( typeof window.attachEvent != "undefined" ) {
    window.attachEvent( "onload", fnc );
  }
  else {
    if ( window.onload != null ) {
      var oldOnload = window.onload;
      window.onload = function ( e ) {
        oldOnload( e );
        window[fnc]();
      };
    }
    else
      window.onload = fnc;
  }
}

addOnloadEvent(myFunc1);
addOnloadEvent(myFunc2);
// ...
```

AND: Say `myfunc2` is for IE 7 only. How to modify the correct/preferred method accordingly?

Comment: You may not like me for saying this, but why wouldn't you just use a framework to deal with such issues?

Comment: I would but I can't in this case. So, could you help me with this, please?

Comment: @ginny Have a look at my answer. Let me know if you need any further explanation than that.

Comment: At the very least, you shouldn't be testing for the event model _everytime_ you want to register an event. This can be easily separated into a common function, to which you pass the _element_, _event type_ and _handler_.

Answer (score 139):

The usage of both is similar, though both take on a slightly different syntax for the event parameter:

### addEventListener ([mdn reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)):

Supported by all major browsers (FF, Chrome, Edge)

```
obj.addEventListener('click', callback, false);

function callback(){ /* do stuff */ }
```

[Events list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference) for `addEventListener`.

### attachEvent ([msdn reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752535(v=vs.85))):

Supported by IE 5-8*

```
obj.attachEvent('onclick', callback);

function callback(){ /* do stuff */ }
```

[Events list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `attachEvent`.

#### Arguments

For both of the methods the arguments are as follows:

1. Is the event type.
2. Is the function to call once the event has been triggered.
3. *(`addEventListener` only)* If true, indicates that the user wishes to initiate [capture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Syntax).

#### Explanation

Both methods are used to achieve the same goal of attaching an event to an element.
The difference being is that `attachEvent` can only be used on older [trident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29) rendering engines ( <s>IE5+</s> IE5-8*) and `addEventListener` is a W3 standard that is implemented in the majority of other browsers (FF, Webkit, Opera, IE9+).

For solid cross browser event support including normalizations that you won't get with the Diaz solution use a [framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks).

*IE9-10 support both methods, for backwards compatibility.

Thanks to [Luke Puplett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107783/luke-puplett) for pointing out that `attachEvent` has been removed from IE11.

#### Minimal cross browser implementation

As [Smitty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1150875/smitty) recommended you can use this [Dustin Diaz](http://dustindiaz.com) addEvent implementation for a solid cross browser implementation without the use of a framework:

```js
function addEvent(obj, type, fn) {
  if (obj.addEventListener) {
    obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
  }
  else if (obj.attachEvent) {
    obj["e"+type+fn] = fn;
    obj[type+fn] = function() {obj["e"+type+fn](window.event);}
    obj.attachEvent("on"+type, obj[type+fn]);
  }
  else {
    obj["on"+type] = obj["e"+type+fn];
  }
}

addEvent( document, 'click', function (e) {
  console.log( 'document click' )
})
```

Comment: @CamiloMartin It's always worth while to put in a good answer if you get a comment like this afterwards, Thanks :)

Comment: `addEventListener` is also supported by IE9+.

Comment: attachEvent has been removed in IE11, so code that detects IE and uses this API will now fail. I've not yet seen this happen but I have noticed that spoofing IE10 agent string from IE11 can cause script errors.

Comment: @LukePuplett The dustin diaz implementation is based on feature detection not browser detection. Is that what you are referring to?

Answer (score 7):

Anyone still hitting this discussion and not finding the answer they were looking for checkout:
http://dustindiaz.com/rock-solid-addevent

This is one of the most elegant solutions I found for those of us with restrictions on using the frameworks.

```js
function addEvent(obj, type, fn) {

    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        EventCache.add(obj, type, fn);
    } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj["e" + type + fn] = fn;
        obj[type + fn] = function() {
            obj["e" + type + fn](window.event);
        }
        obj.attachEvent("on" + type, obj[type + fn]);
        EventCache.add(obj, type, fn);
    } else {
        obj["on" + type] = obj["e" + type + fn];
    }

}

var EventCache = function() {

    var listEvents = [];
    return {
        listEvents: listEvents,
        add: function(node, sEventName, fHandler) {
            listEvents.push(arguments);
        },
        flush: function() {
            var i, item;

            for (i = listEvents.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
                item = listEvents[i];
                if (item[0].removeEventListener) {
                    item[0].removeEventListener(item[1], item[2], item[3]);
                };

                if (item[1].substring(0, 2) != "on") {
                    item[1] = "on" + item[1];
                };

                if (item[0].detachEvent) {
                    item[0].detachEvent(item[1], item[2]);
                };

                item[0][item[1]] = null;
            };
        }
    };
}();

addEvent(window, 'unload', EventCache.flush);
```