# Cancel request if there is new one(promises)

Tags: javascript, promise, axios, cancellation

I send request to server everytime user types something. I use debounce for the 400ms delay:

```
type = debounce((text) => {          
      this.props.actions.loadInfo(text) 
  }, 400);
```

When I type something, stop and start again and repeat it, several requests are send and I receive irrelevant data. I use promises:

```
export const loadInfo = (text) => dispatch => {
  loadData(text).then(result => {
    dispatch(showUserData(result));
  });
};

export const loadData = async (text) => {
  const tabData = await axios.get(`url&query=${text}`);
  return tabData;
}
```

I need somehow cancel previous request if user sends the new one(when he typed something), what is the best way to do that? I expected debounce will help me but not. I use axios. This is not duplicate of questions here, I checked provided solutions but thet don't help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26735236/2630817

Comment: 1) I use axios
2) that won't work as I tried in other case that variant

Comment: again, there is no correct answer

Comment: @rick1 What do you mean by 'correct'? I believe my own answer is correct one, otherwise I wouldn't link it.

Comment: creator of the question didn't mark it as correct so it didn't help him. I will check your variant, maybe it will work

Comment: There's a working demo. The poster abandoned the question and didn't provide any feedback, which isn't a very good practice on SO but it's quite common.

Comment: for me it is unclear what is this._fetchDataCancellation, I do not see such method in the demo that you send.

Comment: It's cancellation object, it's assigned, `this._fetchDataCancellation = CancelToken.source()`. Consider addressing other users with `@`, otherwise they don't receive notifications.

Comment: @estus still I do not uderstand why do you use this.

Comment: in my case it isn't work as I return data in other place. CHeck my code above

Comment: The answer provides this information. It's Axios cancellation API https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation . Storing cancellation object allows to cancel a request. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: I made as you mention but it isn't hwlp me. I think I made mistake in adding your solution to my code @estus

Comment: It won't work in your case because you debounce `props.actions.loadInfo`. It cannot cancel a request in one place and not cancel it in another place. If you need to debounce globally, debounce `loadData` where you have access to axios request, not functions that use it. If you don't need to debounce globally then you need to change the way data is processed in your app. It's specific to React and Redux and the way you use them, while the question didn't focus on that and didn't have relevant tags.

Comment: I do not copied debouce as in your example, I use debounce in the typing function @estus

Comment: @estus can you provide me with the example that will pass to my code? I cannot integrte xode from your demo in my code

Comment: You won't be able to make it the way you showed in the question for the reasons I mentioned. As I said, you need to debounce `loadData`, not `props.actions.loadInfo`. If you have problems with this approach, consider reasking a new question with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that covers all technologies in use - Axios, React, Redux. A working demo of your current attempt will increase chances to solve the problem because it's complex and likely requires to change how data is processed with Redux. I cannot provide an example for now because I don't know how your app works.

Comment: In case this is solved by debouncing `loadData`, it should be something like https://0bin.net/paste/VVzDKApYNqisbwKU#9fOWpDXYKrfvKNyZhL9lPinBDxUNaI2kocTHXqsKCEJ . Hope this helps. Also noticed that demo was wrong in the post I linked, fixed it, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ecsbrz . Also was wrong link in this comment, updated it, sorry for that.

Comment: @estus thanks, it works. It would be great to attach this as an aswer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376322/timeout-on-axios-requests). Axios [cancellation API](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) can be used to cancel old requests. This should be done in a function that does a request (`loadData`) and has direct access to Axios, it may be also debounced:

```
let cancelObj;

export const loadData = debounce((text) => {
  if (cancelObj) {
      this.cancelObj.cancel();
    }

  cancelObj = CancelToken.source();

  return axios.get(`url&query=${text}`, {
    cancelToken: this._fetchDataCancellation.token
  }).catch(err => {
    // request wasn't cancelled
    if (!axios.isCancel(err))
      throw err;
  });
}, 200);
```

Since Redux is used, other solutions may involve it, they depend on how Redux is used.

Answer (score 0):

Even I tried to use debounce function in my code but the problem is that if user types very fast stop and then again start typing, in that case, your input values get updated and UI get distorted, to avoid this I used `XMLHttpRequest` and its `abort()` to cancel the previous calls, if calls do not succeed then it will be canceled,

you can try this solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55509957/9980970