# How to cancel file upload?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

Following function is used to upload a file. Now I want to cancel file upload on button click. How to do this?

```
function submitForm(form) {
        var loader = new Loader({showPgBar : true});
        var progressBar = loader.progressBar();
        loader.show();
        var data = new FormData(form);
        data.append("category", "MEDIA_FILE");
        var csrf_headerName  = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
        var csrf_paramValue  = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: URI.file.singleFileUploadUrl(),
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader(csrf_headerName, csrf_paramValue);
            },
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 1740000,  //29 minutes
            success: function (data) {
                loader.hide();
                mediaFileMetaDataSave(data ,null);
                document.getElementById('media-file-form').reset();
            },
            xhr: function(){
                var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr() ;
                xhr.upload.onprogress = function(data){
                    progressBar.updateStatus(data);
                };
                return xhr ;
            },
            error: function (e) {
                loader.hide();
                toastr.error('Error has occurred while uploading the media file.');
            }
        });

     }
```

Edit:

I have called the xhr.abort() like below. Although I clicked the cancelFileUpload button nothing happens. I have checked the console in browser. No errors appeared as well.

```
xhr: function(){
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr() ;
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(data){
                document.getElementById("cancelFileUpload").onClick = function(){
                    xhr.abort();
                }
                progressBar.updateStatus(data);

            };
            return xhr ;
        },
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: does the request take a very long time or something?

Comment: Nope. But I want to add the cancel option as a new feature

Comment: yah im just saying...they would have to click it quickly after submitting...would they still have time to cancel after deciding to cancel? once the request goes out you can't cancel it...it has to run its course...im not sure if u can do what you want to

Comment: yes. video files take quiet long time to be uploaded

Comment: oh ok its a video

Comment: try using a plugin like jquery file upload

Comment: @PrasannaVenkatesh file upload can be done. Now I want to cancel while uploading

Comment: jquery-file-upload is a plugin which has cancel option

Comment: use `xhr.abort()` method in the `xhr.upload.onprogress = function(data){
                    progressBar.updateStatus(data);
                };` with conditionals for a variable or something when your button attempts to cancel by changing the state of the variable....`if(buttonstate == true) { xhr.abort(); }` something like that...im seeing now how its structured it might be difficult to detect a button click from inside the ajax function

Comment: @ewizard how can I call this function on a button click

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940213/aborting-the-xmlhttprequest this might help you

Comment: @PrasannaVenkatesh link looks like the solution

Comment: possible answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery

Comment: xhr.upload.onprogress = function(data){
                  progressBar.updateStatus(data);
                  document.getElementById("cancelFileUpload").onClick = function(){
                    xhr.abort();
                  }
            };

Comment: @ewizard I did like this. But when I clicked the cancel button nothing happens