# jQuery scrollTo causes problems in IE8 - no script execution after code block

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, mobile-safari, scrollto

I use this JavaScript code to hide the address bar in mobile Safari:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

It works great and doesn't do any harm to other browsers. Only Internet Explorer 8 (which is the oldest IE I have to support) seems to be having problems with it as any JavaScript that comes after that code block isn't executed anymore. Do you have any idea why?

I already googled that some people have problems with `scrollTo` in IE8, but the only resource that could have been helpful was a link to a bug report for jQuery 1.3.3 or something like that. As I am using jQuery 1.9.0 I believe that problem was solved in the meantime.

By the way: Why wasn't I able to find the `scrollTo` method in the jQuery docs? It seems to be some kind of plugin?

Comment: Check the console (`F12`) to see what the javascript error is.

Comment: I would love to, but I don't have access to a real IE8. Firebug does not display anything.

Comment: In my experience IE 9 in IE 8 standards mode *always* acts the same. Perhaps I've just been lucky enough to never find a difference between real IE 8 & IE 9 in 8 standards though.

Comment: Well, it seems like that. In IE9 everything is alright, it's just really IE8 that shows that behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn, that was a tricky one! But the problem simply was that IE8 does not know `addEventListener` - can you imagine that? Instead, IE8 needs `attachEvent`, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657182/correct-usage-of-addeventlistener-attachevent).