# Emulating syntax highlighting with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, syntax

I'm trying something out, just for a bit of fun really, whereby I'm trying to emulate syntax highlighting when code is entered into a textarea on webpage.

I've written a little JS script, but It's throwing errors.
 "cannot set property 'color' of undefined."

To do this I have created a small array of a few example 'buzzwords' to search the entered code for. Then I have split the code string into an array and looped for matches between the two. 
I'm not that familiar with the split method or indeed the search method. How can I get any matches that are found to change colour on the screen in real time?

```
function init() {

window.setInterval(function() {
    var code = document.getElementById("texty").value;
    var buzzword = ["function","()","{","}","[","]",".getElementById",".getElementsByClassName",".style","$"];
    for(i=0; i < buzzword.length; i++) 
    {
        var testers = code.split(" ");
        for(i =0; i < testers.length; i++) 
        {
            if(buzzword[i] == testers[i]) 
            {
                code.search(testers[i]);
                code.match(testers[i]).style.color = 'blue';
            }
        }
    }
}, 10000);

}
```

function init() is executed onFocus of the textarea.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Arbitrary strings don't have styles, they're not part of the DOM, they're just data. You can't apply a style to a random sub-string of a textarea's value. The code `code.match(testers[i]).style.color = 'blue';` will never work.

Comment: continuing with what @meagar said, this is why on websites which format user input there is commonly a textarea where you give input and then another area where you can see a preview of your formatted input, for instance the stackoverflow answer textarea and preview.

Comment: that's a good point. Any ideas on code that will catch certain words in the textarea and color them blue in a seperate 'preview' div?

Comment: @tinkerbot, I've amended my previous wrong answer to allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to have another go at this. Quiet rightly my previous answer was shot down. Here's some code. I've not been able to jsfiddle it, but I have tested it and it works fine:

Some CSS:

```
<style> .blue { color: blue; } </style>
```

Some HTML for testing:

```
<div id="div"></div>
<textarea id="area" onfocus="init()">
  function writeTo() {
    var id = document.getElementById('id');
    var class = document.getElementsByClass('class');
    id.style.color = 'blue';
    var $id = $('#id');
    var array = [];
    var obj = {};
  }
</textarea>
```

Some Javascript. This uses a regex instead of an array. It does a find/replace on the buzzwords, wrapping them in a span with `class="blue"`. The text is then dumped to the awaiting `div`:

```
function init() {
  var area = document.getElementById('area');
  var div = document.getElementById('div');
  var buzzword = /function|.getElementById|.getElementsByClassName|.style|\{|\}|\(|\)|\$|\[|\]/g;
  var text = area.value;
  var replacedText = text.replace(buzzword, function (selection) {
    return '<span class="blue">' + selection + '</span>';
  });
  div.innerHTML = replacedText;
}
```

If you want this to update in realtime (or everytime the user types something) you should bind a `keyup` event to the textarea to run `init` each time. There's more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657182/correct-usage-of-addeventlistener-attachevent).

You should get rid of your `onfocus` event and add this instead:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  document.getElementById('area').addEventListener('keyup', init, false);
} else {
  document.getElementById('area').attachEvent('keyup', init);
}
```

This will ensure that when you type in the `textarea`, the syntax colouring should be ok in the `div`. Make sure the call to your Javascript is at the bottom of your HTML page, rather that in the header otherwise it won't recognise the element.

Comment: Thanks @Andy , your new answer works well! I changed my HTML a bit since I asked, so I had to change your solution a bit but now it works! However, When I carry on typing, the text is still blue. I need it so only the matched word is blue, and then anything not matched is default color. Do you know how to achieve this? :)

Comment: @tinkerbot - I've updated my answer. Hopefully the event listener code will help.

Comment: @tinkerbot, also check to see if you have any other styles called `blue` and change the class in the code to something else if you do.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that :

```
var buzzwords = ['\\(\\)', 'function'];
previewDiv.innerHTML = textarea.value.replace(new RegExp(
    '(' + buzzwords.join('|') + ')', 'g'
), '<span style="color:blue">$1</span>');
```

Don't forget to escape special chars using two backslashes : `.(){}[]$`.