# .addEventListener and .attachEvent correct usage

Tags: javascript

I have a form with a simple calculation, and I have an `.addEventListener` that listens for submitsevents. And this works just great, until I found out that IE7 and IE8 doesn´t support this, but uses its own `.attachEvent`, and I need this to work in both those browsers aswell.

You can see the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/hbrovell/AGBnj/

I have found alot of solutions where you check if the browser uses `.addEventListener` or `.attachEvent` but I can't wrap my head around it how to use it.

For example how would I go about to implement this piece of code correctly to mine?

```
function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
if (element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
} else if (element.attachEvent) {
    element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
}}
```

The elemet in this code, is that the form element in my code? And the eventName is that the submit event?

I'm not able to use any libraries on this project so I need to use plain javascript.

Hope somebody can give me some guidence on how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Correct usage of addEventListener() / attachEvent()?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657182/correct-usage-of-addeventlistener-attachevent?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.getElementById("my-el"),
    action = function (e) { doStuff(); },
    eventName = "click";


// normal browsers
el.addEventListener(eventName, action);

// IE < 9
el.attachEvent("on" + eventName, action);
```

Knowing that, you should be able to see what `addEvent` is doing.

There's a very big ***but*** in there.
What IE gives you back is very different.
While other browsers give you the `e` event argument, IE does not.
While other browsers make `this` the element that was clicked/typed in, etc, IE does not.

That `addEvent` does nothing about that.
That's 100% fine if you just need to know that the event *happened*.
If you need to `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation`, or you need to get event-information, then that function is not going to be good enough to handle it.