# Changing input value with javascript - what went wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text with an input field. I want the field to start as blank, and when clicked upon, set the input's text to its correct value (saved in the "name" field, for instance).

If I do it this way, it works fine:

```
Buy  <input type="text" name="eggs" onclick="this.value=this.name;"> tomorrow.
```

However, if I try to clean the DOM and move the function to a separate javascript file, it stops working:

HTML:

```
Buy <input type="text" name="eggs" onclick="showname(this);"> tomorrow.
```

JS:

```
function showname(el) {
     el.value = el.name;
}
```

```js
function showname(el){
    el.value = el.name;
}
```

```css
.closeform{
    width: 70px;
}

.closeform input {
    width: 70px;
}

.closeform button {
    width: 70px;
}
```

```html
Buy
<span class="closeform">
    <input type="text" name="eggs" onclick="showname(this);"> 
 </span> 
    tomorrow.
```

I'm very new to Javascript - what am I missing here?

Comment: snippet works fine in FF. What browser/version are you using? What does it's error-console say?

Comment: 2 files in same folder: *index.html* (contents: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Demo</title>
  <script src="myscript.js"></script> 
</head><body>
Buy <input type="text" name="eggs" onclick="showname(this);"> tomorrow.
</body></html>`) and *myscript.js* (contents: `function showname(el) {
     el.value = el.name;
}`) works perfectly. You probably didn't post all relevant code.

Comment: @GitaarLAB Thanks! I tried it with Fiddle - maybe the problem is in Fiddle interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say in your question:

> However, if I try to clean the DOM and move the function to a separate javascript file, it stops working

Let's say you have 2 actual files in the same folder:

- *`myscript.js`* contents:

  ```
  function showname(el) { el.value = el.name; }
  ```
- *`index.html`* contents:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html><head><title>Demo</title>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
  </head><body>
    Buy <input type="text" name="eggs" onclick="showname(this);"> tomorrow.
  </body></html>
  ```

  *OR*

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html><head><title>Demo</title>
  </head><body>
    Buy <input type="text" name="eggs" onclick="showname(this);"> tomorrow.
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
  </body></html>
  ```

That *should* work perfectly...

---

However, in the comments you say:

> I tried it with Fiddle - maybe the problem is in Fiddle interface.

**That is where your problem was....**

**There is no separate javascript-file in jsfiddle.**
The three code-blocks (html, js, css) get merged into one file.
Right-click the result-window in jsfiddle and *look at the generated file*.
Then notice the *options* (top right corner) from jsfiddle: by *default* the code is wrapped in an onload-method (suiting to the library you selected or window.onload if you are not using a library).

You can however place the script in the head or body, thereby *not* wrapping your code inside a function's scope (which then [closes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/588079) over the containing identifiers).
See http://jsfiddle.net/wf55a5qb/ for a working example.

The reason your example *stack-snippet* worked here on StackOverflow is that it's snippet-editor *does not* wrap the javascript codeblock in a (onload-like) function (when it combines the three code-blocks).

Having said and explained this, I do encourage you to set your events (Using [`obj.addEventListener`/`obj.attachEvent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10896968/588079) or the direct `elm.onevent`) from the/a script once the elements (that your script manipulates, place script as last element of the html-body) or page (using window.onload/etc) has loaded.

I posted this to clear up what *actually* went wrong so you don't make false models in your head about how javascript works (like "an external script runs in it's own scope" <sup>which no-one claimed but might be an assumption you might make</sup>) whilst still learning it!

Comment: What a fantastic answer! I'm not allowed to vote up yet - thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in JavaScript has a *scope*. Where you are defining your function, it is not visible to the `input` so the input doesn't know that function even exists. You can use `window` to make the function visible to it:

```
<input type="text" name="eggs" onclick="window.showname(this);"/> 

window.showname = function (el)
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/253tvo0c/7/)

I don't recommend global functions though. So then what else?

---

You can use the `onclick` function in JavaScript. To find elements in JavaScript, you use *selectors*. I'm using `getElementById()` this will get an element by it's id. A list of selectors are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)

```
<input id="my_input" type="text" name="eggs"/>
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('my_input').onclick = function () {
    //Use this to refer to the element
    this.value = this.name;
};
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/253tvo0c/8/)

---

When doing this. Make sure all your code is wrapped in a `window.onload`. This will make sure the code is run at the right time:

```
window.onload = function () {
    //Your code
};
```

JSFiddle automatically puts your code in this.