# does something like onevent eventListener exists

Tags: javascript, events

Does something like an `onevent` event listener exist?
I would like to do something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("event", function(event) {
  console.log(event.type);
});
```

Comment: Please review [ask] and elaborate on what you want, what you've tried, and why it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct usage of addEventListener() / attachEvent()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657182/correct-usage-of-addeventlistener-attachevent)

Comment: I want to know does event listener "onevent" or "event" or something like that

Comment: No, not like that, you set the event you want to catch, not _an event_ as in any ... how is the browser suppose to know which one you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bind all events on a DOM element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848598/how-can-i-bind-all-events-on-a-dom-element)

Comment: ok,is there a way to log to console event.type everytime any event happens(this is now tottaly different question but the purpose of the first question was to get answer for this qestion)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439570/how-do-you-log-all-events-fired-by-an-element-in-jquery

Comment: @Matija — I think you are asking "Is it possible to set an event listener that will trigger for any event, no matter if it is a click, a blur, a load or something else?". Could you edit the question (not just commenting below) to clarify?

Answer (score -1):

in the event you want logged you can just add "e" in the fuction and do console.log(e);
for example `$('#theEvent').on("blur",function(e){
             console.log(e);
             });`
and if you want to catch a certain event you can do

```
$('#theEvent').on("blur click",function(e){
        if(e.type === "click"){
        console.log(e.type + "The user did click");
    }else{
          console.log(e.type + "The user did blur");
         }
         });
```

An other way to do it with case switch

```
$('#theEvent').on("blur click focus",function(e){
    switch(e.type){
        case "click":   
            console.log("The user clicked.");
            break;
        case "blur":
            console.log("The user blurred.");
            break;
        case "focus":
            console.log("The user focused.");
            break;
    }   
});
<!-- html sample -->


<input type='text' id="theEvent"/>
```

This is a random example but i think you get the idea you can do alot of if statements, so when the right event was triggered it will run the code

Comment: From what you said that's what i understood you asked

Comment: `$` throws a reference error since it is undefined. If `$` is supposed to be jQuery and you add it, then `theEvent` won't match anything, there is no `<theEvent>` element in HTML (and you seem to be confusing events with elements).

Comment: This is why its call an example its because it has nothing to do with his code

Comment: And yea i forgot the "#" symbol sorry :)