# Getting my function to re-execute whenever the browser window screen size is adjusted

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make my simple javascript function (no jQuery) log a message to the console when the browser is resized to over or under 890px. This code works on load, but only states the starting width when the page is loaded:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 890) {
     console.log('Less than 890px');
    } else {
     console.log('890px or more');
    }
```

But my code below using a window event doesn't work:

```
if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent('onresize', function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 890) {
     console.log('Less than 890px');
    } else {
     console.log('890px or more');
    }
})};
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here? I'm relatively new to javascript. Thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
 if (window.innerWidth < 890) {
     console.log('Less than 890px');
    } else {
     console.log('890px or more');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`onresize` is to be used as an attribute in your html. e.g. `<body onresize="resizePage()"></body>`

The correct event is `resize`. Try following

```
if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent('resize', function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 890) {
     console.log('Less than 890px');
    } else {
     console.log('890px or more');
    }
 })
}
```

Please **note**, you can also consider using `addEventListener`. For details, refer to another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10896968/1132354)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', function() {
        if (window.innerWidth < 890) {
         console.log('Less than 890px');
        } else {
         console.log('890px or more');
        }
    });
}
else if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        if (window.innerWidth < 890) {
         console.log('Less than 890px');
        } else {
         console.log('890px or more');
        }
    }, true);
}
else {
    console.log('browser does not support Javascript event binding');
}
```

Comment: thanks - I saw this on another page. What does the ', true' part do?

Comment: [check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following code

```
    window.onresize = resize;

    function resize()
    {
       if(document.body.clientWidth < 890)
          {
             alert("resize event detected!");
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const on = (e, i, t = window) => typeof t.addEventListener === 'function'
    ? t.addEventListener (e, i)
    : t.attachEvent ('on' + e, i)
const test = () => console.log (window.innerWidth < 890 ? '< 890' : '>= 890')

on ('resize', test)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    //your code here
};
```

Comment: Why not use `window.attachEvent`?

Comment: @Justinas Why not use `window.addEventListener`

Comment: @Keith Still same question... It should be explained instead of `just try this`