# Child window close button

Tags: javascript

This is my code. When I click the close button on the child window it will display suresh on the screen but if I call **popuponclick()** function at the time itself suresh is getting displayed. What I do??

```js
popuponclick = function() {
  window.ChildWindow = window.open('GOLF12/shared/launchpage.html',
    'popupWindow',
    'width=700,height=700');
  window.ChildWindow.attachEvent("onunload", OnChildWindowClose());
}
OnChildWindowClose = function() {
  document.getElementById("my").innerHTML = "suresh";
  window.ChildWindow = null;
};
```

Comment: what is your actual requirement?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please explain what you want to happen, and what is actually happening at the moment?

Comment: Remove the () from `OnChildWindowClose()` - when you call it with `OnChildWindowClose()` it executes immediately. Your statement should be `attachEvent("onunload", OnChildWindowClose);`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_

Comment: Also attachEvent is IE<9, addEventListener is more supported

Comment: When I click the child window close button after that "Suresh" should get displayed on screen @AmeerPappay

Comment: @mplungjan It's not working for me. If I remove the () it's getting "(index):47 Uncaught TypeError: window.ChildWindow.attachEvent is not a function" this error.

Comment: 1. Why use attachEvent in the first place? It is an IE only construct only needed for IE<9.

2. Use addEventListener instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657182/correct-usage-of-addeventlistener-attachevent

Comment: Thanks, **attachEvent** worked in IE. But addEventListener not worked in chrome. Why? What do I need to do?  @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

This will likely work better on your server

It does not run if there is a popup blocker, then you will need to test if ChildWindow was opened correctly

this [fiddle works](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5oL81axe/), but stacksnippets fail on the popup blocking

```js
var ChildWindow;
function  popuponclick() {
  ChildWindow = window.open('GOLF12/shared/launchpage.html',
    'popupWindow',
    'width=700,height=700');
  setTimeout(function() { // we need to have the new page active
    ChildWindow.addEventListener("unload",OnChildWindowClose)
  },100)
}
function OnChildWindowClose() {
  this.opener.document.getElementById("my").innerHTML = "suresh";
  this.opener.ChildWindow = null;
};
```

```html
<button onclick="popuponclick()">Click</button>
<span id="my"></span>
```

Comment: This code working without the URL. But I need with URL. What do I do?

Comment: The url has to be from the same origin as the page that opens it

Comment: If I give the URL its not worked properly. It has the same issue as my code.

Comment: See my update. The browser will open a new window with '' and then change the URL, triggering the unload. We need to allow the switch